# Doxygen not documenting main function

Tags: c++, doxygen, program-entry-point

I only have 1 file called main.cpp.

I am able to get my functions documented, but unable to get my `int main()` to get documented.

```
/**
 * @file
 */

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/**
 * Prototypes
 */
int one();
bool two();
int next();

/**
 * @fn int main()
 */
int main(){
    /**
     * @var int max
     * @brief max
     */
    int max;
...
}
```

/**
 * \fn int one()
 * \brief ...
 */

My `int max;` is not being documented and `int main()` is not showing up in doxygen.

Comment: What would be the point of documenting `main`? First you already know the signature and what it does and second you are not allowed to call it.

Comment: @nwp What do you mean you are not allowed to call it? Do you mean doxygen will not document anything inside int main(){}?

Comment: No, I mean the standard forbids you from doing for example `int foo(){ return main(); }`. And you can't access `max` either.

Comment: @nwp So how do I document variables in main. I don't care that I already know what it does.

Comment: You write a comment. The only people who need documentation on what `max` does are people who are changing the code of `main`. Maybe it helps if you think about interface and implementation. Doxygen assumes you document interfaces while you want to document implementations. Either change your goal or your tool.

Comment: You will have had a waring like "warning: documented symbol `int main' was not declared or defined.", by providing a prototype (as side note: always a god idea to have prototypes for argument checking) of main the function will be documented. Regarding documentation inside a function see also INTERNAL_DOCS.